# xfrac resets \oldstylenums to computer modern

Tags: xetex, fontspec, xfrac

Using `xelatex`, `fontspec` and `unicode-math`, old style nums work just fine. But when using `xfrac`, the `oldstylenums` seems to be reverted to some basic version of the command, using a pixely computer modern font. 
How can I avoid this?

[image: comparison of output (with and without xfrac)]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,paper=a4,parskip=half,ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}


\begin{document}

with xfrac \oldstylenums{10827}

\end{document}
```

xelatex outputs the following (only when using xfrac), and I understand this is the problem, but why does it happen and how do I keep xfrac from doing this?

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TS1/TeXGyrePagella(0)/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TS1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 12.
```

(And, btw: Is this an okay way to setup`fontspec` and `unicode-math` using xelatex? I am just switching from pdflatex.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`xfrac` loads the `textcomp` package, and `textcomp` redefines `\oldstylenums`. Load `xfrac` before `fontspec`, than the definition of `fontspec` will win:

```
\documentclass[11pt,paper=a4,parskip=half,ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\begin{document}

with xfrac \oldstylenums{10827}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is that kind of a bug that should be reported? (And if so, for which packet?)

Comment: I'm discussing this already on the latex team list, imho we should avoid that textcomp redefines oldstylenums in such cases.

Answer (score 6):

I can’t explain the innards of `xfrac`, but if you want lowercase numbers and vulgar fractions with Palatino, you don’t need `xfrac`.

Instead, get [FPL Neu](https://github.com/rstub/fplneu), which, unlike TeX Gyre Pagella, defines the `dnom` and `numr` features needed for arbitrary fractions. Then use the `\vfrac` command provided by `xltxtra`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}% loads fontspec, realscripts, and metalogo
\setmainfont{FPL Neu}[Numbers=OldStyle]
\begin{document}
10827

\vfrac{123}{456}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: I've chosen Ulrike's answer as the "accepted" one as it most closely answers the exact question, but yours also helps. Thank you!